# Drupal 7 - Redirect 404 errors to home page

Tags: redirect, drupal, drupal-7

I have someone who wants me to send or redirect all 404 errors to the main page of a website. We are using Drupal 7.54. On the site information page (.../admin/config/system/site-information) in the 'Error Pages' block, it allows me to put a link for 'Default 403 (access denied) page' and 'Default 404 (not found) page.' I just tried typing "node" for the 404, so it would redirect to the main page of the website. However, this does NOT redirect me to the main page. It does redirect, but not to the main page. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Could the answer be somewhere in includes/common.inc (similar to what was found on https://www.drupal.org/node/178653#comment-985665)? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did you try to type `<front>` instead node into 404 ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the code below in your theme.

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
   $status = drupal_get_http_header("status");  
   if($status == "404 Not Found") {
      drupal_goto('<front>');
   }
}
```

Hope this helps you.